# A word that means itself

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for a word that means itself? For example the word *word* means itself and is a word.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word), emphasis mine:

> An **autological word** (also called **homological word** or **autonym**) is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses (e.g. the word "short" is short, "noun" is a noun, "English" is English, "pentasyllabic" has five syllables, "word" is a word, "sesquipedalian" is a long word, "adjectival" is adjectival; see Wiktionary for a [partial list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_autological_terms)).

Comment: Also see wikipedia entry for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference#In_language which discusses autological words and also autograms (sentences which inventories its own letters and punctuation marks).

Comment: So an autological word is sort of like an onomatopoeic word, except that instead of sounding like what it represents, it IS what it represents.

Comment: My favorite autological word is sesquipedalian.  More specifically, my favorite autological word is "sesquipedalian."

Comment: This answer could benefit from some supporting definitions. Or an explanation as to why these terms are used.